# Updating a row based on values from a previous row in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table similar to this:

```
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| event_type_id |     start_time      |      end_time       | hours_from_last_event |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|             1 | 2019-06-07 0:00:00  | 2019-06-07 22:00:00 |                       |
|             1 | 2019-06-09 21:00:00 | 2019-06-09 23:00:00 |                       |
|             1 | 2019-06-10 16:00:00 | 2019-06-10 20:00:00 |                       |
|             2 | 2019-06-05 14:00:00 | 2019-06-05 19:00:00 |                       |
|             2 | 2019-06-07 03:00:00 | 2019-06-07 21:00:00 |                       |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

For each row, I want to set `hours_from_last_event` by subtracting the `end_time` from the previous row from the `start_time` of the current row ONLY when the `event_type_id` are equal. If there is no previous row for that row, it should be `NULL`.

So the above table would become:

```
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
| event_type_id |     start_time      |      end_time       | hours_from_last_event |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|             1 | 2019-06-07 0:00:00  | 2019-06-07 22:00:00 | NULL                  |
|             1 | 2019-06-09 21:00:00 | 2019-06-09 23:00:00 | 47                    |
|             1 | 2019-06-10 16:00:00 | 2019-06-10 20:00:00 | 17                    |
|             2 | 2019-06-05 14:00:00 | 2019-06-05 19:00:00 | NULL                  |
|             2 | 2019-06-07 03:00:00 | 2019-06-07 21:00:00 | 32                    |
+---------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

We can assume that an `id` column exists to uniquely identify each row.

I already know I can use the `TIMEDIFF()` function to find the difference in hours, but how should I go about doing this in MySQL?

Comment: It's generally considered a bad idea to store easily derived data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `lag()` for this purpose:

```
select t.*,
      timestampdiff(hour, lag(end_time) over (partition by event_type_id orde rby start_time), start_time) as diff
from t;
```

You cannot use this in an `update` though . . . except through a `join`:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               timestampdiff(hour, lag(end_time) over (partition by event_type_id order by start_time), start_time) as diff
        from t
       ) tt
       on tt.event_type_id = t.event_type_id and tt.start_time = t.start_time
    set t.hours_from_last_event = tt.diff;
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity why can't `LAG` be used in an update?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Well, you can try it and see the error that you get.  I suspect the reason is because it would be unclear whether the referenced "previous" row would use the updated values or original values.

Comment: this seems to work on my local machine but unfortunately the lag function is not supported on the server version that I'm using, thanks anyway